# Extension of Dirac measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions

A Dirac measure is a measure $\delta_x$ on a set $X$ defined for a given $x\in X$ and any set $A\subseteq X$ by
$$\delta_x(A)=\begin{cases}0, & x\notin A, \\ 1, &x\in A.\end{cases}$$

I wonder whether it is possible to construct some measure $\tilde{\delta}_x$ such that $\tilde{\delta}_x(A)=1$ if $x\subseteq A$ and $\tilde{\delta}_x(A)=0$ if $x\not\subseteq A$, where $x\subseteq X$ is a compact set.

Comment: Yes, this $x$ is called an atom. The limitation that you have on such a thing is with its domain: no nonempty proper subsets of an atom can be in the $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: Hi lan, thanks for your reply. I see that an atom is a measurable set which has positive measure and contains no set of smaller positive measure. But is there any way to proving the existence of such a measure given $A,X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$?

Comment: Sure, you pretty much just do it once you pick what other sets you want in there besides $\emptyset,A,A^c,\mathbb{R}^n$. If you want it can be all subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ that contain either no elements of $A$ or all of them. (What you actually asked for originally is not possible, though.)

Comment: I see. Given a set $X\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$, the simplest $\Sigma$ is given by $\{\varnothing, A, A^c, X\}$. Then we can define $$\tilde{\delta}_A(y)=\begin{cases}0, & A\not\subseteq y \\ 1, &A\subseteq y\end{cases}.$$ $\tilde{\delta}_A(y)$ is a measure on $(X,\Sigma)$. Is it correct? By the way, what does "not impossible" mean?

Comment: You can do that for sure. What you can't do is do this thing where the measure is $0$ for every set that doesn't contain all of $A$ and otherwise $1$.

Comment: Yes, but is it possible if $\Sigma=\mathcal{B}(X)$? It seems impossible.

Comment: You need the $\sigma$-algebra to be such that if $B \in \Sigma$ then either $A \subset B$ or $A \cap B=\emptyset$. This intuitively means that the measure sees $A$ basically like a singleton, since it can't see proper subsets of it.

Comment: Get it. Thanks again.